# Place MFC dialog for in the middle

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I start my MFC dialog form on very top of windows.

```
BOOL StatusDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
...
SetWindowPos(&this->wndTopMost,0,0,0,0,SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOSIZE);
...
}
```

Now it placed on left upper corner, and I need to place in the middle of screen center.

According MSDN :

```
BOOL WINAPI SetWindowPos(
  _In_     HWND hWnd,
  _In_opt_ HWND hWndInsertAfter,
  _In_     int  X,
  _In_     int  Y,
  _In_     int  cx,
  _In_     int  cy,
  _In_     UINT uFlags
);
```

I can use X and Y coordinates, but in this case I suppose I need to know monitor resolution. I have feeling that somewhere should be function or flag JUST_SET_WINDOW_IN_CENTER. What is easy way to place window in the center?

Comment: There are [simpler ways to center a window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1a3x359y.aspx).

Comment: Also in Dialog editor, you can click the title bar, click F4 to see properties. At the bottom of dialog properties page, set "Position -> Center -> true"

Comment: Are you sure you do not want to center it on the middle of the dialog that called it instead of in the center of the screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy way:

```
BOOL CAboutDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
   CDialog::OnInitDialog();
   CenterWindow();
   return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: It works if the user wants to center it to parent Window or if it has no parent; but if it has a parent and user wants to center on the screen it will not work. We are not sure what user wants to do.

Comment: In https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1a3x359y.aspx the Remarks section says if user wants to center dialog to screen,  pass the value returned by `CWnd::GetDesktopWindow` as `pAlternateOwner` argument of  `CenterWindow` function.